# Invalid long:"" Exception

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I have 2 edit text fields ETPredictKm(long value) and ETPredictFuelQty(double value). If I insert one value the other gets autogenerated when i click the respective EditText. I am using onFocusListener. My problem is that when i insert the km value to calculate the fuelQty it gets calculated properly. But when i input the fuel qty and click on ETPredictKm I get the invalid long: "" Exception.

Please help me with your suggestions.
Thank you.

Here some code:

```
 try
     {
        predictKm = Long.parseLong(ETPredictKm.getText().toString()); //Get the error here
        predictFuelQty = Double.parseDouble(ETPredictFuelQty.getText().toString());
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ne)
    {
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(isChkLastMileage1 ==true || isChkLastMileage5==true||isChkLastMileage10==true)
    {

        if(ETPredictKm.hasFocus())
        {
           if(predictFuelQty!=0)
            {
                  //predictionMileage is double too
              predictKm =(long) (predictionMileage*predictFuelQty);
              ETPredictKm.setText(String.valueOf(predictKm));

            }
        }
      else if(ETPredictFuelQty.hasFocus())
        {
            // This value is calculated properly            
           if(predictKm!=0)
             {
            predictFuelQty =predictKm/predictionMileage;
        ETPredictFuelQty.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(predictFuelQty)+" Litres");
             }

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got this working by just putting both the parsing statements into different try-catch blocks. Like so :-

```
try
        {
            predictKm = Long.parseLong(ETPredictKm.getText().toString().trim());

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ne)
        {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            predictFuelQty = Double.parseDouble(ETPredictFuelQty.getText().toString().trim());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ne)
        {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to trim the whitespaces out before you convert to long/double like this

```
try
     {
        predictKm = Long.parseLong(ETPredictKm.getText().toString().trim()); //Get the error here
        predictFuelQty = Double.parseDouble(ETPredictFuelQty.getText().toString().trim());
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ne)
    {
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And put in null/empty checks for `ETPredictFuelQty.getText()` and `ETPredictKm.getText()` before cast datatype conversion, if only one of your fields will be set at any point, the other one will be null/empty, and hence will throw an exception

Comment: I got this working by putting the parsing statements into seperate try-catch blocks. Not sure if its a right practice, but worked for me. Thanks for the explanation and your time though, Iam sure it will only expand my knowledge.